# html email design for gmail – doesn't show images

Tags: css, gmail, html-email

I'm designing a email template and test it on various clients including gmail.
Gmail just won't display the images though. Don't tell me gmail doesn't support it cause I'm getting images all the time.
The logo is of course in the html code, not css.

Here's my code for the header-table:

```
<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 1.5em;">
<tr>
<td>
<p>                 
<img style="display: block; margin: auto;" align="center" alt="Example logo" src="http://example.com/media/images/email/example-logo.png"/>
</p>                
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Difficult to tell without a piece of code

Comment: [See here first](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post some codes so that we can help

Comment: Learn how to ask questions... Are we supposed to guess your code?

Comment: How we can test it without any given code? By the way what is this `alt="Example" logo" `?

Comment: gmail no longer defaults to blocking images, I believe. They have implemented the cache system that allows their users to safely download the temp files from a sandbox server hosted by Gmail rather than directly from html source listed. To your issue at hand, is it displaying the red 'X' of death(click to display images) or are the images just simply not there?

Comment: Might be this link solved your problem. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919?hl=en

Comment: @Gortonington you are right now they use proxy server to show the images, but its have some bugs. The link I've posted will solved OP Problem.

Answer (score 1):

you have mistake

> alt="Example" logo"

This html must work

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#fefefe">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <!--header starts-->
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" width="100%"><img src="http://siteurl.com/logo_beta.png" alt="Company Logo" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                    <p><strong><font size="2.5" face="Times New Roman, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Hi User!</font></strong>
                    </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td><span><br></span></td></tr>
                <!--header ends-->
                <!--content starts-->
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="center">
                        <table width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                            <!--Table Content-->
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--content ends-->
                <!--fotter starts -->
                <tr>
                    <td align ="left">
                    <p><strong><font size="2.5" face="Times New Roman, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Thanks<br>
                            With best wishes, Company</font></strong>
                    </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>    
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gmail automatically shows you the images in your messages. If you have a slow Internet connection or limited mobile data, you may want to change your setting so that Gmail asks you before showing images.

> Note: This is the reason we shouldn't depend on images. Better way is
>   to use the style `alt text` so if images is blocked by email provider due to low internet connection or due to security issue a mail still
>   should work.

Gmail scans every message for suspicious content and if Gmail considers a sender or message potentially suspicious, images won’t be displayed and you’ll be asked whether you want to see the images.

Actual content is from [gmail support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919?hl=en).